# How are sparse Ax = b systems solved in practice?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Let A be an n x n sparse matrix, represented by a sequence of m tuples of the form (i,j,a) --- with indices i,j (between 0 and n-1) and a being a value a in the underlying field F.

What algorithms are used, in practice, to solve linear systems of equations of the form Ax = b? Please describe them, don't just link somewhere.

Notes:

- I'm interested both in exact solutions for finite fields, and in exact and bounded-error solutions for reals or complex numbers using floating-point representation. I suppose exact or bounded-solutions for rational numbers are also interesting.
- I'm particularly interested in parallelizable solutions.
- A is not fixed, i.e. you don't just get different b's for the same A.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I solve linear equation AX=b for sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717451/how-can-i-solve-linear-equation-ax-b-for-sparse-matrix)

Comment: Lots of history on this but a good starting point is [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-38424-3_8.pdf).  I've implemented both block Lanczos (a variant for Gf(2)) and block Wiedemann on massively parallel SIMD computers and others.  Can't go wrong with Lanczos assuming you just need a single solution.

Comment: @TheGreatContini: MasPar, Connection Machine ?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: That question is specific to C++ code and its answer does not describe the algorithms for solving such systems, particularly w.r.t. the different parameters I mentioned.

Comment: @TheGreatContini: Thanks for the link. Do you suppose you could expand that into an answer?

Comment: Though this particular is way too broad in my opinion, it is much better suited for [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), rather than SO. [This question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/81/20688) can get you started.

Comment: @YvesDaoust MasPar described here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MasPar .

Comment: @einpoklum I'm bit squeezed on time, which is why I left the quick comment.  If I can find the time on the weekend, then will expand.  Parallelising these algorithms is rather straightforward but it depends upon the architecture you are working on.  The general process involves repeatedly multiplying a matrix by a set of vectors.  This parallelises by splitting the matrix into rows, each row multiplies by the vector separately, and then you combine the results to get the new vector.  Need to use standard data structure for sparse matrices (holding indices of nonzero entries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main two algorithms that I have used and parallelised are the [Wiedemann algorithm](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/profs/Francois.Morain/Master1/Crypto/projects/Wiedemann86.pdf) and the [Lanczos algorithm](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-38424-3_8.pdf) (and their block variants for GF(2) computations), both of which are better than structured gaussian elimination.

The LaMacchia-Odlyzo paper (the one for the Lanczos algorithm)  will tell you what you need to know.  The algorithms involve repeatedly multiplying your sparse matrix by a sequence of vectors.  To do this efficiently, you need to use the [right data structure](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sparse-matrix-representation/) (linked list) to make the matrix-vector multiply time proportional to the number of non-zero values in the matrix (i.e. the sparsity).

Paralellisation of these algorithms is trivial, but optimisation will depend upon the architecture of your system.   The parallelisation of the matrix-vector multiply is done by splitting the matrix into blocks of rows (each processor gets one block), each block of rows multiplies by the vector separately.   Then you combine the results to get the new vector.

I've done these types of computations extensively.  The original authors that broke the [RSA-129 factorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Words_are_Squeamish_Ossifrage) took 6 weeks using structured gaussian elimination on a 16,384 processor MasPar.  On the same machine, I worked with Arjen Lenstra (one of the authors) to solve the matrix in 4 days with block Wiedemann and 1 day with block Lanczos.  Unfortunately, I never published the result!